# How can I diable register global on wampserver3.1.9_x64 localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, wamp, register-globals

I have an web application i want to install on my local host server using wamp, the app requires register global OFF on server configuration.

I have tried some solutions online but is not solving the problem.

[image]

Comment: You should upgrade to PHP 7.

Comment: Seriously?? PHP5.2?? PHP7.0 is no longer supported PHP5.2 has not been supported since `6 Jan 2011` You really should upgrade to PHP 7.3 for new projects and if this App you are trying to use will not run in PHP7+ Then you should not be using that either

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find the php.ini for apache and set "register_globals = off".
The wamp manager icon has a menu list, you can edit the apache configuration there.